# How to create a rounded image input for a form in html and css

Tags: html, css, input, forms

I have a form i'm making, and at the top i'd like to have an rounded image input like the one in the screenshot below, so when the user clicks it, they can upload their own image.[My design for a website, including the image input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzyWh.png)

Comment: use `border-raadius` properties. ref : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

Comment: Maybe, i'm not describing my problem clearly but that's as clear as I can describe it.

Comment: So is your problem that the image is not rounded, or that you want it to trigger a file picker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i got your question, this is the way of doing it :
**by having a hidden input** and **jQuery**

**HTML:**

```
<form>
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" style="border-radius:50%"/>
   <input type="file" id="myfile" style="display:none"/>
</form>
```

and **javascript**

```
$('#image').click(function(){
    $('#myfile').click()
})
```

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r89gbqh6/

Hope that helps! ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, this was what i needed, but why didnt the picture upload when i selected it.

Comment: For that to work, you need to have some server side code running.. or if you want to just show the preview before uploading.. check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/12446/

Comment: Thanks @mithu Modal

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>

<body>

<img src="sample.jpg" alt="profilepic" style="width:200px">
</body>
```

Use border radius as specified above. And make the image an link.

Comment: a link to what? i want the user to be able to pick an image from their device

Answer (score 1):

You can use "border-radius: 100%;" to make an image smooth out to a circle.
See the [border-radius](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp) demos at W3Schools. The same property works on field elements too (input, textarea, etc), but 100% will make any inputs an oval, so I'd recommend using a smaller value.

I've provided an example below of an image and an input field.

```css
img{
  border-radius: 100%;
 }
 input{
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
 }
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt=""/>
<br/>
<input type="text"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, i don't have any problem with design,i just need to click the circle and the it opens up a file explorer,so i can upload a picture to it

Comment: Ah. Then if you want to make the image clickable to make a file upload possible, you'll need a bit more.

First, you'll need to have a form hidden on your page (like "display: none") with the file upload attribute (ex: `<input type="file" name="uploadfile" id="uploadfile"/>`), then use something like Javascript to make the form active once the image is clicked, then you can run an [AJAX Request](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to upload the photo in the background

Answer (score 1):

[Upload file or image](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

You need to use PHP or any other scripting language along with HTML.
Refer above link to PHP code.